# How to draw a circle from a given radius

Tags: android, android-canvas, audio-recording

I have a amplitude value that get from audio signal in other class. It can get that value by call the function `getAmp` in `CircleRenderer`. Now, I have a class CircleRenderer that to draw the circle. I want to draw circle which its radius is set by the amplitude value. Could you see my class and suggest to me how to modify it. Currently, I just compare with threshold value to decide draw or not.

```
public class CircleRenderer extends Renderer
    {
      private Paint mPaint;
      private boolean mCycleColor;
      private int amplitudeThreshold = 5;
      private int amp = 0;
      /**
       * Renders the audio data onto a pulsing circle
       * @param canvas
       * @param paint - Paint to draw lines with
       */
      public CircleRenderer(Paint paint)
      {
        this(paint, false);
      }
      public void getAmp(int dbAmp)
      {
        amp=dbAmp;
      }
      /**
       * Renders the audio data onto a pulsing circle
       * @param canvas
       * @param paint - Paint to draw lines with
       * @param cycleColor - If true the color will change on each frame
       */
      public CircleRenderer(Paint paint, boolean cycleColor)
      {
        super();
        mPaint = paint;
        mCycleColor = cycleColor;
      }

      @Override
      public void onRender(Canvas canvas, AudioData data, Rect rect)
      {
        if(mCycleColor)
        {
          cycleColor();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < data.bytes.length - 1; i++) {
          float[] cartPoint = {
              (float)i / (data.bytes.length - 1),
              rect.height() / 2 + ((byte) (data.bytes[i] + 128)) * (rect.height() / 2) / 128
          };

          float[] polarPoint = toPolar(cartPoint, rect);
          mPoints[i * 4] = polarPoint[0];
          mPoints[i * 4 + 1] = polarPoint[1];

          float[] cartPoint2 = {
              (float)(i + 1) / (data.bytes.length - 1),
              rect.height() / 2 + ((byte) (data.bytes[i + 1] + 128)) * (rect.height() / 2) / 128
          };

          float[] polarPoint2 = toPolar(cartPoint2, rect);
          mPoints[i * 4 + 2] = polarPoint2[0];
          mPoints[i * 4 + 3] = polarPoint2[1];
        }

        if(amp > amplitudeThreshold )
        {
          // Amplitude is bigger than normal, make a prominent line
          canvas.drawLines(mPoints, mPaint);
        }


        // Controls the pulsing rate
        modulation += 0.04;
      }


      float modulation = 0;
      float aggresive = 0.33f;
      private float[] toPolar(float[] cartesian, Rect rect)
      {
        double cX = rect.width()/2;
        double cY = rect.height()/2;
        double angle = (cartesian[0]) * 2 * Math.PI;
        double radius = ((rect.width()/2) * (1 - aggresive) + aggresive * cartesian[1]/2) * (1.2 + Math.sin(modulation))/2.2;
        float[] out =  {
            (float)(cX + radius * Math.sin(angle)),
            (float)(cY + radius * Math.cos(angle))
        };
        return out;
      }

      private float colorCounter = 0;
      private void cycleColor()
      {
        int r = (int)Math.floor(128*(Math.sin(colorCounter) + 1));
        int g = (int)Math.floor(128*(Math.sin(colorCounter + 2) + 1));
        int b = (int)Math.floor(128*(Math.sin(colorCounter + 4) + 1));
        mPaint.setColor(Color.argb(128, r, g, b));
        colorCounter += 0.03;
      }  

    }
```

Comment: What about using [drawCircle()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawCircle(float,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint))?

Comment: Actually, I want to make some visualization that refers from https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/renderer/CircleRenderer.java

Comment: use canvas for this.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya: I used canvas for that task. The problem in here is that I cannot control the size of circle as well as when it draw or not. I need used above code to create some animation

Comment: Why did you post a link... which shows a code that's identical to the one you already posted?

Answer (score 0):

Do it with canvas.drawCircle

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
   super.onDraw(canvas);

   canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
}
```

EDIT:
For further information you can look up the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html).

[Here](http://android-coding.blogspot.de/2012/04/draw-circle-on-canvas-canvasdrawcirclet.html) is another Tutorial for drawing Circles with Canvas.

Comment: Actually, I want to make some visualization that refers from https://github.com/felixpalmer/android-visualizer/blob/master/src/com/pheelicks/visualizer/renderer/CircleRenderer.java

Comment: No. I modified that link to my task. The code in that link only draws circle every time. In my task, it will draw depending on the radius which is amp of signal

Comment: I think doing it like the way I posted above is easier. For restoring the canvas (for a new amp value) you can use "canvas.restore();" (saving it before would not be neccesary in my opinion because you want to redraw the circle with smaller/larger radius).

Comment: I found a solution that is double radius =amp; But it will lost some animation that is main goal of my task